# Google Middlewire Authentication in MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core, google-signin, google-authentication

I was trying to add google authentication in my MVC application.
I followed all the steps and registered the middlewire in Configure method in Startup.cs

```
   app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
        {
            ClientId = Configuration["Google:ClientID"],
            ClientSecret = Configuration["Google:ClientSecret"],
            Scope = { "email", "openid" }

        });
```

I am saving ClientID and ClientSecret in appsettings.json.

In developers.google.com I am using G+ api for signin purposes.

using https://localhost:44386 as Authorized JavaScript origins

and https://localhost:44386/signin-google as Authorized redirect URIs

The issue is the page shows the **Allow** and **Deny** access page and upon clicking on the **Allow** ,the page stays in loading state and never redirects to `ExternalLoginConfirmation.cshtml` page.

Using default single user authorization mvc core template for this. Any help where I am doing wrong.

This is the OUTPUT stream from my MVC Core app.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:61356/signin-google?state=CfDJ8MgRzE29TklJksJpDlbDmWeE9W4z9qKrqyko5mov7FHppD2rTlEeUUBP0nFXZ-edch6RmiDobEj-88mvuEG1a_-X087pVbicROYtDDBl1MnQyMxGaN7pImaOhrA_c5XCpRgR3G73GVME-Qk4km2tqO5iP-25ccTwySQYmDd3ham2pmWO5CBwoABnavk9Tu0Ym2XOoWRstcuGEUSqecuj8fLGRMjyBmrBW-mTSXDuKrHu6kLg7kUze48fyjg2o9BHq68JS5F3SA9_q2bqxr2DKg4MrY5vmvJoADmcUAcE6MFONEeQCgEm0j71cdFuIaw46g&code=4/F179kp-WOfRd88aBQPdRsSfynoRwES3gUn7bhHvCw0A&authuser=0&hd=motorolasolutions.com&session_state=f02757ef58689502dbceb4b6cc6bd131dfa2d805..5a04&prompt=consent
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware:Information: Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
```

Its saying Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed.